# Monotone functions and distribution functions

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I found this quote in a textbook on measure theory I'm studying:

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Since $f$ has only countably many discontinuities, we may assume without loss of generality that $f$ takes the upper value at a discountinuity and is therefore a distribution function.

(In this book, a distribution function is simply defined as an increasing, right-continuous function.)

What does this statement mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, what they mean is this:

Suppose $f$ has a discontinuity at some $y\in[a,b]$.  Since $f$ is right-continuous, $f_y:=\lim_{x\rightarrow y^+}f(x)$ exists.  Since $f$ has at most countably many discontinuities, we may assume w.l.o.g. that $f(y)=f_y$.

Here, the "upper value" is $f_y$, which, as $f$ is increasing, satisfies $f(x)\leq f_y$ for all $x\leq y$.